# Superimpose two figures

Tags: matlab, adobe-illustrator

I have two figures - one is a phylogenetic tree and the other is a skyline plot (a line plot with shaded bits).

I want to superimpose the tree onto the skyline, like this:

[image]

Both figures are tiff files with white backgrounds.

Is this possible with MATLAB? My line plot is made with MATLAB.

I also have illustrator (CS6) but am a complete newbie to that...

Thanks!

Comment: Are both of the images the same dimensions?

Comment: @rayryeng yes they are and when plotting them in subplots they line up. I know I can just plot the line over the tree.tif image but I need to do this the other way around, i.e. with the tree on top.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Load in both images, then merge them assuming a transparency of `0.5`.  As such, let's say your tree diagram was in an image called `imtree` and the skyline plot is in an image called `imskyline`.  Load these into MATLAB, then simply do this sum:

```
out = uint8(0.5*double(imtree) + 0.5*double(imskyline));
```

After this, display your image using `imshow(out);` and see what it looks like.  Hopefully this will work, as I don't have access to your actual images!

You may have to play around with the constants.  Perhaps weight the tree more while the skyline plot less.  If the above doesn't work, try something like:

```
out = uint8(0.75*double(imtree) + 0.25*double(imskyline));
```

---

Alternatively, if the above doesn't work, try doing [`imfuse`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imfuse.html) to blend the two images together in a natural way:

```
out = imfuse(imtree,imskyline,'blend','Scaling','joint');
```

What the above code does is that it blends the images naturally, and scales the colours between the two images in such a way that they will play nicely with each other.

Comment: Giving both a degree of transparency would allow for mixing, but in the example they one is 'on top' of the other.

Comment: @DennisJaheruddin it appears that the images are alpha matted together which is why I suggested fusing them. I wasn't sure as to how exactly they were to be superimposed but it looks like what I suggested worked. Thanks for your comments anyway!

Answer (score 0):

I can't try it at the moment, but I think you want to put one image on top of eachother.

Assuming that the top image is `NaN` on places where you can see the second image:

```
idx= ~isnan(frontimage)
backimage(idx) = frontimage(idx)
```

You may need to do some padding or scaling first as this requires the images to be of the same size.